# PromQL Memory Usage > 75% and < 90 % - Avoid alert triggering for both when memory above 90% and 75%

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, promql

I'm trying to setup an alert when memory utilization is greater than 75% and 90%, at the same time when it is >90% it is also triggering the alert for >75% as per query, what could be best way to ignore 1 rule to trigger alert for >75% and >90% individually.

`(memory_info_rss{service=~".*app.*"} / 2000 * 100 > 75) AND (memory_info_rss{service=~".*app.*"} / 2000 * 100 < 90)`

Comment: Your query seems fine. You can concise it a bit with `memory_info_rss{service=~".*app.*"} / 2000 * 100 >75 <90`, though. What is your problem?